My override file won't load
I tried to override a vendor file. The path of the original file is:
vendor/amasty/module-extra-fee/view/frontend/web/template/fee/item/checkbox.html
My new file is located at:
app/design/frontend/Amasty/JetTheme_majestic/Amasty_ExtraFee/web/template/fee/item/checkbox.html
However, it is still using the vendor file. I also added the following in app/design/frontend/Amasty/JetTheme_majestic/requirejs-config.js
this is the content
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        'Amasty_ExtraFee/template/fee/item/checkbox.html': 
            'Amasty_JetTheme_majestic/Amasty_ExtraFee/template/fee/item/checkbox.html'
    }
} 
};


If you want to override html file using theme then not need to add any code on requirejs-config.js file
Just copy that file and paste in to below path of your theme.

app/design/frontend/Amasty/JetTheme_majestic/Amasty_ExtraFee/web/template/fee/item/checkbox.html

Using custom Module:

Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            'Amasty_ExtraFee/template/fee/item/checkbox.html': 'Vendor_Module/template/fee/item/checkbox.html'

        },
    }
};

Now create this checkbox.html in app/code/Vendor/Module/web/template/fee/item/ folder and make necessary changes.
Run below commads for deploy static content

php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean



Thank you, i figured it out already, i have a different folder name from the registration.php, my mistake
